# Product Delete Observer

Tags: magento, observer-pattern

I want to create an observer for Product deletion. Means when admin deletes a product, during deletion I want to add some custom functionality in this process. Currently I'm using

```
catalog_controller_product_delete
```

for this purpose. But it is doing nothing for me. Please help me. How can I do something extra during product deletion?

I want to send deleted product id to my API where I have copy of this product so that I can delete it from there too, but it is not triggering the event. I know this because I am triggering sendProductDelReq() method by `<method>sendProductDelReq</method>` and for verification I've put a die in this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the people that have encountered the same problem and who were hoping to find an answer here. 
I found the problem.
First of all, how are you deleting the product?
If you are deleting the product from within the product edit page, chances are your observer won't work. 
If you are deleting the product from within the Product Grid page, your observer will probably work fine.

The issue is that the event: **catalog_controller_product_delete**, only gets dispatched in the **massDeleteAction()** in the *productController()*.
 And ***NOT*** inside the **deleteAction()**.

I've already submitted this issue as a bug at magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking.

To fix this, paste this:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_controller_product_delete', array('product' => $product));
```

Inside your deleteAction(), right before `$product->delete();`

Like so:

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->load($id);
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        try {
            Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_controller_product_delete', array('product' => $product));
            $product->delete();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('The product has been deleted.'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $this->getResponse()
        ->setRedirect($this->getUrl('*/*/', array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))));
}
```

Comment: I don't see the needs for this. This solution works better without any code modification -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14211286/515268

Comment: @dayson, I don't see how the other solution is **better**? You are achieving the same thing. The guys at Magento admit it is a bug as you can read in the comments of my [pull request](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/9#issuecomment-5059665) which is also mentioned in the answer by jmva. If you feel like it is wrong to edit core code, then just extend the productController in your own module and edit it there.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a bit for a similar issue today I found another event for delete thanks to [this pull request](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/9).

You can use **catalog_product_delete_before** event, which is dispatched in Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeDelete(). Works for individual deletes in both grid and edit page.

This event is not shown on the [Magento event list](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method#list_of_events) created using

```
grep -rin -B2 -A2 "Mage::dispatchEvent" app/* > events.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You should actually be using the `catalog_product_delete_before` and `catalog_product_delete_after`events.

More on it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14211286/515268

Answer (score 0):

I guess **catalog_product_delete_after_done** is the proper Event

Mage_Catalog_Model_Product has the following dispatchEvent:

```
    public function delete()
{
    parent::delete();
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_delete_after_done', array($this->_eventObject=>$this));
    return $this;
}
```

Otherwise, you could get the case that the product is deleted in Magento but not in your API

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

> model_delete_after

without modifying any core file.

Here's a brief of the after delete function dispatching the model_delete_after event.

```
protected function _afterDelete()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('model_delete_after', array('object'=>$this));

    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_delete_after', $this->_getEventData());
    return $this;
}
```