# Magento Product Delete Observer?

Tags: magento

I am trying to locate the production deletion observer in Magento as I want to run some custom functionality whenever I delete a product from my site.

I found this: catalog_controller_product_delete, but I have read it has been removed? I am using magento 1.7.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use either of these - depending on whether you want to observe the before or after delete event:

```
catalog_product_delete_before

catalog_product_delete_after
```

There is also the `catalog_product_delete_after_done` event which can be observed for products

Comment: Check my updated question with the code I am using. I have tried these and they arent working. Perhaps I have something wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Drew What is difference between catalog_product_delete_before and catalog_product_delete_after ?